# How to get data from third party rest API in MVC 6.0 and asp net core application

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an asp net core 1.0.1 project with AnjularJs 2 where I am getting data from web api not sql database. I went through different article on google but didn't get best way to call http get, post, put and delete API from asp.net core application whether I am successfully able to make same call in MVC 5 which is as below so can anyone guide what would be equivalent of below code in asp net core?

```
public static HttpWebResponse Get(string requestUrl, Dictionary<string, string> headers, string contentType, string acceptType)
{
    //Create http Request
    HttpWebRequest httprequest = WebRequest.Create(requestUrl) as HttpWebRequest;

    //Add all headers.
    httprequest.ContentType = contentType;
    httprequest.Accept = acceptType;
    httprequest.UserAgent = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent.ToString();
    foreach (var header in headers)
        httprequest.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
    httprequest.Method = GET;

    //Get response
    HttpWebResponse response = httprequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were quite close:

```
public static async Task<HttpWebResponse> Get(string requestUrl, Dictionary<string, string> headers, string contentType, string acceptType, string userAgent)
{
    //Create http Request
    HttpWebRequest httprequest = WebRequest.Create(requestUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
    //Add all headers.
    httprequest.ContentType = contentType;
    httprequest.Accept = acceptType;
    httprequest.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = userAgent;
    foreach (var header in headers)
    {
        httprequest.Headers[header.Key] = header.Value;
    }

    httprequest.Method = "GET";
    //Get response
    HttpWebResponse response = await httprequest.GetResponseAsync() as HttpWebResponse;
    return response;
}
```

Things to note:

1. The method must be async because in .NET Core there's no synchronous version of `GetResponse()`. This means that you should also make your controller action that is calling this method asynchronous so that you can now `await` on the result of the Get method: `public async Task<IActionResult> Index() { ... }`
2. There's no more `HttpContext.Current`. The `userAgent` is passed as parameter now. Inside your controller you could retrieve it like this: `string userAgent = this.Request.Headers["User-Agent"];`

Also bear in mind that it is very important to properly dispose the `HttpWebResponse` instance after you have finished using it. Make sure that you have wrapped in a `using` statement the call to this method:

```
using (var response = await Get(...))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution however my project structure is as follow controller => services => project1HttpWebRequester => project1HttpClient. I need UserAgent in project1HttpClient so It means I need to pass UserAgent all the way form controller to project1HttpClient? Secondly, Is it possible, If I don't want to use async function at all?

Comment: Yes, you need to pass the user agent through all the layers of your application. Also if you don't want an asynchronous version you could always call `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` on the HTTP response in order to block your main thread until the request completes but personally I would recommend you against doing that. In .NET Core you should be accustomed that asynchronous is the idiomatic way of doing things and you should adapt your APIs accordingly.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Is there a way to create a common interface type to accept different types of parameters based on different authentication methods and then create a dictionary based on the authentication type? For e.g. Basic Auth would have Username and Password fields whereas JWT would have only the Token field.